# Roman alpha iso Italicized alpha in formulas

Tags: italic, roman

I'd like to use a Roman alpha iso an italicized version in my formula. How can i do this, since \text doesn't work..

```
\begin{align*}
    V_\text{af}  &= V_\text{B} + \alpha (V_\text{max} – V_\text{B}) \\
    V_\text{aan} &= V_\text{B} + \alpha (-V_\text{max} – V_\text{B})
\end{align*}
```

Comment: avoid using `\text` in math (and if you do use it use `_{\text{af}}` dont rely on `_\text` failing to give an error, but it would be better to use `\mathrm` , in unicode-math  you could use `\mathrm{\alpha}`. I assume you mean you want an upright _greek_ alpha U+03B1 α not a Latin alpha U+0251 ɑ